# Do Chain Notes count as multiple notes?

Tags: beat-saber

Beat Saber 1.20 added Chain Notes which are made up of multiple small note blocks. When looking at the notes per second for a track on the song selection screen, does a Chain Note count as a single note or multiple notes?

[image: A Chain Note]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain notes count as a single note. Below is a 1.20 custom map edited to have a single chain with multiple links.

[image: Song with 1 note]